# Recover removed partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, partition-recovery

My Debian system hat a default encrypted installation ("use whole disk with encrypted LVM" in setup). Then I used gnome-disks to do something on an microSD card that had the same setup. EFI Partition, swap partition, luks partition with ext4 inside. I accidentally used my harddrive and deleted the LUKS partition. The system still worked. Until I rebooted. Now it wont find the LVM volume anymore.

Is there any way to recover from this? I can boot up live media or the recovery mode from the debian netinstaller CD-Rom.

EDIT: I am right now doing the same in a VM to test on, ill report back with more infos when I am finished!

Comment: Testdisk is for recovering full partitions or disks. but remember, you must always restore to another disk. Never try to recover data to the disk you are recovering from.

Comment: Thanks. I always only do stuff as read only on "critical" media. Maybe I got an LVM archive file, then I can do `vgcfgrestore`. I alredy mirrored the whole drive to an image file on disc, so no more data can be lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when you delete a partition, its actual contents remain intact. It's only when you *create* one that the partitioning tool will prompt to erase old data.

So you should be able to just re-add the partition using `fdisk` or `gdisk` at the same starting point, just make sure to *not* accept fdisk's prompt to remove the old LUKS signature. (Although if you get the prompt in the first place, that means you've found the right offset.)

(I don't recommend trying this with GParted or GNOME Disks. But if you do anyway, then again double-check that you're selecting a non-destructive option like "Unformatted".)

testdisk can help you find where the partition starts (...if it knows what LUKS is), although in any case it won't be far from the end of the preceding partition and usually aligned to the megabyte. (Sometimes even going by trial-and-error and accepting fdisk's default offer will work -- though again, if you get the "Wipe old signature?" question, *do not* accept it.)

The partition's size / end point is not as important; if the entire missing area belonged to one partition then just accept the maximum size.

Should you ever do this again, do not reboot: as long as the partition is still in use, its position and size can be obtained from the kernel.

Comment: You, sir, saved my butt! Worked perfectly! Computer is up and running again!